# In Go, can we synchronize each key of a map using a lock per key?

Tags: go, concurrency, mutex

In Go, can we synchronize each key of a map using a lock per key? 
Is map level global lock always required?
The documentation says that any access to map is not thread safe. But if a key exists, then can it be locked individually?

Comment: You can lock your map's keys by wrapping it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly, but if you are only reading pointers off a map and modifying the referents, then you aren't modifying the map itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple implementation of what you want: [mapmutex](https://github.com/EagleChen/mapmutex).

Basically, a mutex is used to guard the map and each item in the map is used like a 'lock'.