# How to gc a map of mutexes in Go?

Tags: go, thread-safety

I am making a cache wrapper around a database. To account for possibly slow database calls, I was thinking of a mutex per key (pseudo Go code):

```
mutexes = map[string]*sync.Mutex // instance variable

mutexes[key].Lock()
defer mutexes[key].Unlock()

if value, ok := cache.find(key); ok {
   return value
}
value = databaseCall(key)
cache.save(key, value)
return value
```

However I don't want my map to grow too much. **My cache is an LRU** and I want to have a fixed size for some other reasons not mentioned here. I would like to do something like

```
delete(mutexes, key)
```

when all the locks on the key are over but... that doesn't look **thread safe** to me... How should I do it?

Note: I found this question
[In Go, can we synchronize each key of a map using a lock per key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40560007/in-go-can-we-synchronize-each-key-of-a-map-using-a-lock-per-key) but no answer

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to do, but the code you showed is totally broken: You **must** **not** copy a sync.Mutex. Use `*sync.Mutex` everywhere.

Comment: thanks @Volker  , I edited (was pseudo code). so if I didn't have any constraint on my map of key -> mutex I would not care, but what if I try to delete a key in that map and another thread is waiting on the mutex, is there a design pattern to do that effectively?

Comment: The line `delete(mutexes, key)` deletes something from a map. This is a write. All writes from different goroutines have to by synchronised to all other writes and reads to this map. It does not matter if the map entry is a sync.Mutex or an int. If the delete to the map is non-racy, then you can delete a mutex which is held by an other goroutine. I still have no real idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: Your map lookups for a particular key will race with operations on the mutex referenced by the key. Hence you might want to have another mutex which would guard accesses to the map. A goroutine dealing with a DB query would first lock the "record" mutex, then the map mutex, delete the map entry and unlock both mutexes. A goroutine which would want to know the result of a query would first lock the map's mutex and then to a lookup.

Comment: Still, I smell like having a dedicated goroutine listening on a channel for requests and mediating access to such map would be a better solution. See examples [here](https://dave.cheney.net/2016/11/13/do-not-fear-first-class-functions).

Comment: @Thomas,

 1. The idea to delete/GC a mutex, means that when deleting you'll need to check for a mutex state. Why would we want to delete a locked mutex on a state which is currently locked, right? However, from what I know, you cannot really check a mutex state. 
 2. What would be a benefit of having a global var with a map of mutexes as compared to using mutex lock/unlock inside cache.save() , i.e. linked to a context of specific operation? What are the expected benefits?

Comment: @mpmlj 2. having the mutex before the call to database() saves the cost of calling the remote database more than once for hot keys. 1. yes that's why I ask :) I don't know how I could safely delete that key (haven't tried above suggestions yet)

Comment: @Thomas,
Well... I have an idea I don't really like, but can work. You can keep a state of a mutex in the same manner: in addition to mutexes[key]MutexObjHere you can have a separate map of states, mutex_states, and assign mutex_states[key] := struct{}{} on Lock, and delete(mutex_states, key) when you are doing mutexes[key].Unlock().
And then you can refer to this map to understand if you can delete a mutex during your GC pass. But frankly, I have a gut feeling there could be a cleaner and simpler solution on architectural level of your project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A map of mutexes is an efficient way to accomplish this, however the map itself must also be synchronized.  A reference count can be used to keep track of entries in concurrent use and remove them when no longer needed.  Here is a working map of mutexes complete with a test and benchmark.

(UPDATE: This package provides similar functionality: https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/singleflight )

mapofmu.go

```
// Package mapofmu provides locking per-key.
// For example, you can acquire a lock for a specific user ID and all other requests for that user ID
// will block until that entry is unlocked (effectively your work load will be run serially per-user ID),
// and yet have work for separate user IDs happen concurrently.
package mapofmu

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

// M wraps a map of mutexes.  Each key locks separately.
type M struct {
    ml sync.Mutex              // lock for entry map
    ma map[interface{}]*mentry // entry map
}

type mentry struct {
    m   *M          // point back to M, so we can synchronize removing this mentry when cnt==0
    el  sync.Mutex  // entry-specific lock
    cnt int         // reference count
    key interface{} // key in ma
}

// Unlocker provides an Unlock method to release the lock.
type Unlocker interface {
    Unlock()
}

// New returns an initalized M.
func New() *M {
    return &M{ma: make(map[interface{}]*mentry)}
}

// Lock acquires a lock corresponding to this key.
// This method will never return nil and Unlock() must be called
// to release the lock when done.
func (m *M) Lock(key interface{}) Unlocker {

    // read or create entry for this key atomically
    m.ml.Lock()
    e, ok := m.ma[key]
    if !ok {
        e = &mentry{m: m, key: key}
        m.ma[key] = e
    }
    e.cnt++ // ref count
    m.ml.Unlock()

    // acquire lock, will block here until e.cnt==1
    e.el.Lock()

    return e
}

// Unlock releases the lock for this entry.
func (me *mentry) Unlock() {

    m := me.m

    // decrement and if needed remove entry atomically
    m.ml.Lock()
    e, ok := m.ma[me.key]
    if !ok { // entry must exist
        m.ml.Unlock()
        panic(fmt.Errorf("Unlock requested for key=%v but no entry found", me.key))
    }
    e.cnt--        // ref count
    if e.cnt < 1 { // if it hits zero then we own it and remove from map
        delete(m.ma, me.key)
    }
    m.ml.Unlock()

    // now that map stuff is handled, we unlock and let
    // anything else waiting on this key through
    e.el.Unlock()

}
```

mapofmu_test.go:

```
package mapofmu

import (
    "math/rand"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func TestM(t *testing.T) {

    r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(42))

    m := New()
    _ = m

    keyCount := 20
    iCount := 10000
    out := make(chan string, iCount*2)

    // run a bunch of concurrent requests for various keys,
    // the idea is to have a lot of lock contention
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(iCount)
    for i := 0; i < iCount; i++ {
        go func(rn int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            key := strconv.Itoa(rn)

            // you can prove the test works by commenting the locking out and seeing it fail
            l := m.Lock(key)
            defer l.Unlock()

            out <- key + " A"
            time.Sleep(time.Microsecond) // make 'em wait a mo'
            out <- key + " B"
        }(r.Intn(keyCount))
    }
    wg.Wait()
    close(out)

    // verify the map is empty now
    if l := len(m.ma); l != 0 {
        t.Errorf("unexpected map length at test end: %v", l)
    }

    // confirm that the output always produced the correct sequence
    outLists := make([][]string, keyCount)
    for s := range out {
        sParts := strings.Fields(s)
        kn, err := strconv.Atoi(sParts[0])
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
        }
        outLists[kn] = append(outLists[kn], sParts[1])
    }
    for kn := 0; kn < keyCount; kn++ {
        l := outLists[kn] // list of output for this particular key
        for i := 0; i < len(l); i += 2 {
            if l[i] != "A" || l[i+1] != "B" {
                t.Errorf("For key=%v and i=%v got unexpected values %v and %v", kn, i, l[i], l[i+1])
                break
            }
        }
    }
    if t.Failed() {
        t.Logf("Failed, outLists: %#v", outLists)
    }

}

func BenchmarkM(b *testing.B) {

    m := New()

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        // run uncontended lock/unlock - should be quite fast
        m.Lock(i).Unlock()
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks but I'm not sure to understand where you can limit the size of the map?

Comment: @Thomas map entires are only retained while a request is in progress, as soon as Unlock() is called, if that is the last one for the specified key, the entry is removed.  The map will always be as small as possible.  Does that answer it or do you actually need some separate limit? If so why?

Comment: indeed that's the best approach

Comment: Had a tremendous memory leak that was resolved by this approach - thx

Comment: Can you explain to me plz why you make this asign?
_ = m

Comment: Is it because of the gorutines later? You make a call to the variable, so the compiler won't let the definition for later?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a simple similar implementation: [mapmutex](https://github.com/EagleChen/mapmutex)

But instead of a map of mutexes, in this implementation, a mutex is used to guard the map and each item in the map is used like a 'lock'. The map itself is just simple ordinary map.

Comment: can you explain briefly how you achieve this?

Comment: 1. Use a map A to store many 'locks'. Say using 'user id' as keys, `A[user-1] = true` means it's locked, `A[user-1] = false` or there is no key as `user-1` means the lock is released. In this way, each user doesn't affect others.

2. User a mutex to guard the map ( or just use sync.Map, the performance difference is related to the key access pattern ) to set some value to `true` (that is to lock) or to delete some key (that is to release the lock)
@Thomas

Comment: And how do you achieve "performance" with the lock on one key not affecting other keys?

Comment: Say you want to do action A which is to change some DB records, it takes 2 seconds. If you use one 'lock' for all users, then each user will affect others(because they need the same 'lock'). If you use the 'map' method I described above, when user B and user C both want to do action A, they just need to lock the same 'mutex' to change the `map`(which is fast, say 0.1 seconds, and then the 'mutex' is unlocked), and do action A at the same time. In this way, better performance is gained. @Thomas